# Using Javascript to load an html page inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to get each option to load a different page in frame

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function selectCountry()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("country");
document.getElementById("frame").src=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].html;
}
</script>
</head>
<form action="">
<select id = "country" onchange="selectCountry()">
<option value="america">America</option>
<option value="austria">Austria</option>
<option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="bosnia">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="france">France</option>
<option value="germany">Germany</option>
<option value="greece">Greece</option>
<option value="hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="italy">Italy</option>
<option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="russia">Russia</option>
<option value="serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="uk">UK</option>
</select>
</form>
<iframe id = "frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

but the page does not load in the iframe, apache gives an object not found message despite the page being in the same folder as index.html above. I have tried changing the line:

```
document.getElementById("frame").src=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].html;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("frame").src=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex] + ".html";
```

but no joy. plz help.

Comment: You want .value(), not .html()

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
function selectCountry(){
 var mylist=document.getElementById("country");
 document.getElementById("frame").src=mylist.value+'.html';
}
```

or

```
mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].value
```

`value` is missing.